# Create multiple rows with date info (Month, Year, etc.) based on date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know if that is possible to accomplish, but I want to create timeline of rows for each unique **AuthId** based on 2 columns (**AuthStartDate** and **AuthEndDate**).

```
declare @authorization table
(AuthId INT, AuthStartDate DATE, AuthEndDate DATE);

INSERT INTO @authorization
VALUES
(123, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17')

SELECT * FROM @authorization
```

What I want to get:

| AuthId | AuthStartDate | AuthEndDate | MonthStartDate | MonthEndDate | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | 2021-12-19 | 2021-12-31 | December | 2021 |
| 123 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | January | 2022 |
| 123 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 | February | 2022 |
| 123 | 2021-12-19 | 2022-03-17 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-17 | March | 2022 |

I would share my code, but I have no idea even how to start.

Comment: Check out some variant of a calendar table or tally table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use recursive to make a result for each month from a date range before self-join, because you need to get original data from your expected result.

then use `DATEADD` with arithmetic to get the first day of months, there is a trick we need to use `CASE WHEN` or `IIF` compare.

- `DATENAME` function help us get the month of name easier.
- `EOMONTH` function help us get the end day of months.

the query looks like below

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT AuthId,AuthStartDate,DATEADD(month,1,AuthEndDate) AuthEndDate
  FROM @authorization
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AuthId,DATEADD(month,1,AuthStartDate),AuthEndDate
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE DATEADD(month,1,AuthStartDate) <= AuthEndDate
)
SELECT a1.*,
       IIF(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, c.AuthStartDate), 0) < a1.AuthStartDate,
          a1.AuthStartDate,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, c.AuthStartDate), 0)) MonthStartDate,
       IIF(EOMONTH(c.AuthStartDate) < a1.AuthEndDate,
          EOMONTH(c.AuthStartDate), a1.AuthEndDate) MonthEndDate,
       DATENAME(month,c.AuthStartDate) Month,
       year(c.AuthStartDate) year
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN @authorization a1
ON c.AuthId = a1.AuthId
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7955748318246a1f4c2d4abc73337a55)

Comment: Thank You, @D-Shih. It looks like it works, except the MonthEndDate in your case is the last day of the month, but needs to be the AuthEndDate

Comment: @Yara1994 Sorry I miss the point I edited my answer, just use another `IIF` compare the date

Comment: Hi, @D-Shih.
Is it possible to develop same logic without using CTE? I need to create a dynamic report in Tableau, however (unfortunately) Tableau is not supporting CTE. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive CTE to generate the records month by month and some date functions like `EOMONTH` and `DATEADD` to manipulate the dates.

```
declare @authorization table
(AuthId INT, AuthStartDate DATE, AuthEndDate DATE);

INSERT INTO @authorization
VALUES
(123, '2021-12-19', '2022-03-17'),
(987, '2022-02-01', '2022-04-05');

;WITH GenerateMonths AS 
(
   SELECT AuthId, AuthStartDate, AuthEndDate
        , AuthStartDate AS MonthStartDate
     FROM @authorization
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT AuthId, AuthStartDate, AuthEndDate
        , Next.MonthStartDate
     FROM GenerateMonths
    CROSS
    APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GenerateMonths.MonthStartDate)) AS MonthStartDate) AS Next
    WHERE Next.MonthStartDate < AuthEndDate

)
SELECT *
     , IIF(AuthEndDate < EOMONTH(MonthStartDate), AuthEndDate, EOMONTH(MonthStartDate)) AS MonthEndDate
     , DATENAME(MONTH, MonthStartDate) AS MonthName
     , YEAR(MonthStartDate) AS Year
  FROM GenerateMonths
 ORDER BY AuthId, MonthStartDate
```

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4500967afbbca47c79cb92ab6800ba85)

Comment: Thank You, @MarcinJ.
It looks like it works, except the MonthEndDate in your case is the last day of the month, but needs to be the AuthEndDate

Comment: @Yara1994 Indeed, I overlooked that, fixed now.

Comment: Hi, @MarcinJ. Is it possible to develop same logic without using CTE? I need to create a dynamic report in Tableau, however (unfortunately) Tableau is not supporting CTE. Thank You

Comment: You can't really do it without a CTE unless you have some kind of calendar month that would give you a row per month. You can create a temp table from a CTE based query in Tableau, it's [described here](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions).